# Is “needs details or clarity” connected to the help center article on questions that are automatically blocked for not meeting quality standards?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, moderation, moderators

I have noticed that [dozens of old questions have been recently unilaterally closed in Web Apps SE as “needs details or clarity”](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584), or closed as duplicates of questions also closed as “needs details or clarity”. (Some of them are also locked.) None of them have any comments indicating what specific details or clarity would make them reopenable, and this comment was left on those questions by the moderator who closed them:

> This question doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

The comment links to the help center article, “[Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)”

That help center article is for users whose questions were *automatically* blocked by the SE server and are automatically notified that their “question does not meet quality standards”. However, the questions in question were posted successfully and not blocked, so that article should not apply to them.

I made this meta post because I’m puzzled that the “needs details or clarity” close reason has been connected with the message for questions that are *automatically* blocked by the SE server. I’m wondering whether this was one of the intentions or purposes for the “needs details or clarity” close reason.

Is it appropriate to close questions as “needs details or clarity” and direct the askers to the “[Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)” help center article? Are those two connected? I want to know if this is an appropriate practice, SE-wide, not just specific to Web Apps SE.

Comment: How do you know these people aren't question banned? Seems like you should be asking all this on webapps meta instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don’t know if they are question banned or not. (There is nothing to suggest that they are, which puzzles me.) I want to know if this is an appropriate practice SE-wide, not just specific to Web Apps SE.

Comment: Do you see it anywhere else? if not asking about something that's not happening isn't going to be too fruitful.

Comment: This seems like a site-specific issue to be discussed on that site's Meta (or you can [contact us](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact) for clarification) – but I'd agree that that Help Center article should not be linked to in these cases, because it's about a completely different situation, as you point out.

Comment: @V2Blast I’ve [asked for clarification at Web Apps SE Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5008/7584). I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it.

Comment: @V2Blast :  I think that you should take note that your [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388332/is-needs-details-or-clarity-connected-to-the-help-center-article-on-questions#comment1294919_388332) was quoted by [galacticninja's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5021/88163) to [As of today, April 2023, who do we understand that is our intended audience and what is the first that we tell them about how to participate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012/88163). It will be nice if you join this discussion and the one linked in the above comment.